# Server is not serving files from assets/images

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just deployed the site using Mina. All the JS and CSS works, but there are some files in assets/images that are being used by colorbox that are not being served.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://pykture.com/assets/controls.png
```

I have changed this to true

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

but still no luck. How can I get these image files served?

Comment: Yeah. I precompiled the assets

Comment: Does `public/assets/controls.png` actually exist? `config.serve_static_assets` isn't relevant, they would either all be broken or all be fine if that were the problem.

Comment: Yeah. Here it is in public/assets: controls-8c7c9ca38d939b137235ab1496201823.png
controls-8e899fb84b99ba6f03cb879824c7895d.png

Comment: Not sure if this may be part of the issue, one of those copies is from my local development and the other created when I compiled for VPS production

Comment: What is colorbox? Are you using asset helpers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use this - https://github.com/knapo/jquery-colorbox-rails - gem.

The problem is that the references to assets (like controls.png) in the CSS are not wrapped in an asset helper.  If you need to write your own SCSS file, make sure you wrap references to these images in URL helpers.  Like so:

```
image-url('colorbox/controls.png')
```

Then the CSS in production will not contains URLs like `http://pykture.com/assets/controls.png`, and instead will include URLs like `http://pykture.com/assets/controls-8e899fb84b99ba6f03cb879824c7895d.png`